# How to use constant of filename that including in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP file index.jsp in WEB-INF directory with following code.

**FilesName.java**

```
package pack.cms;

public class FilesName {
//all jsp files name
public static final String FIILE_CMS_HEADER     =   "cms-header.jsp";
}
```

**Index.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="pack.cms.*"
import="java.util.*"
%>

<%@ include file=FilesName.FIILE_CMS_HEADER %>
```

FilesName.FIILE_CMS_HEADER = cms-header.jsp

**I am getting following error**

Fragment "FilesName.FIILE_CMS_HEADER" was not found at expected path /CMS/WebContent/FilesName.FIILE_CMS_HEADER

What can be the problem and solution?

Comment: The file is expected directly under WebContent.

Comment: Problem is why it is not allowing me to use FilesName.FIILE_CMS_HEADER? if I use cms-header.jsp instead of FilesName.FIILE_CMS_HEADER  then it works fine.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. What is this - FilesName.FIILE_CMS_HEADER? Is it defined in a properties file? If yes, please use the proper syntax to read a propery from the properties file.

Comment: I have edited my question.Please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. <%@ include file=FilesName.FIILE_CMS_HEADER %> only allows String value in file attribute. Like file ="abc.jsp" .
2. If your are looking for scriplet resolution for the name of jsp to be included , use some thing like this. `<jsp:include page="<%=FilesName.FIILE_CMS_HEADER%>" ></jsp:include>`